# Excel extract values from column with offset

Tags: excel, extract, offset, csv

I have an Excel sheet like shown in the screenshot. An I want to make new columns that contains the value of the same position on each row with a continuous offset of 13 cells (I have color coded an example).

Could anyone help me?

I have been trying

```
=OFFSET($B$2, (13 * B) - 1, 0)
```

but I don't seem so do it right.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: What about `=OFFSET($B$2,13*(ROW()-2),0)`

Answer (score 1):

Since what you need is always the number besides "A", the easiest and most general solution is:

```
=FILTER(B:B, A:A="A")
```

The function means search column A for the value "A" and return the correspondent value from column B — *I am using A:A and B:B to say that we want the whole column, but you can also define ranges.*

It only works for Microsoft 365 users; if you have an older version the offset should do the job:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,13*(ROW()-2),0)
```